# swagger-codegen: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to read API

Tags: json, code-generation, swagger, swagger-php

I am trying to work with `swagger-codegen` to generate code based on my Swagger resource file.  However, I am running into the following error when attempting to generate code:

```
base path is http://my.documentation.com/api/docs/v1.json
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://my.documentation.com/api/docs/v1.json/authenticateUser
```

It seems that `swagger-codegen` is attempting to read the method definition by appending the operation name after `v1.json`, but I am not sure why, as the operation name is defined inside `v1.json` itself:

```
{
    "basePath":"https://my.api.com/v1",
    "swaggerVersion":"1.2",
    "apiVersion":"1.0.0",
    "resourcePath":"v1",
    "apis":[
        {
            "path":"/authenticateUser",
            "description":"Authenticates a user into the API",
            "operations":[
                {
                    "method":"GET",
                    "summary":"Authenticates a user into the API",
                    "nickname":"authenticateUser",
                    "parameters":[
                        {
                            "paramType":"query",
                            "name":"username",
                            "type":"string",
                            "required":true,
                            "description":"Name of of user to authenticate"
                        },
                        {
                            "paramType":"query",
                            "name":"password",
                            "type":"string",
                            "required":true,
                            "description":"User's password"
                        }
                    ],
                    "notes":"Returns access token in the response object"
                }
            ]
        },
    ...
    ]
}
```

I am not entirely sure what format `swagger-codegen` is expecting. Do the basePath for the API and the documentation for the API need to be the same? Note that the documentation for the documentation is hosted on a separate basePath than the API itself. I am not sure if this matters.

I will also note that my swagger resource file `v1.json` was generated with `swagger-php` and is working fine with `swagger-ui`.

Comment: It appears the documentation basePath needs to be set to `http://my.documentation.com/api/docs/`. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the basePath to `http://my.documentation.com/api/docs/` instead of `http://my.documentation.com/api/docs/v1.json` resolved the issue.